# React Native Realm sync with atlas issue

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, realm

I am using Realm Sync with MongoDB Atlas in a React Native app. The use case I am working on is that I want to create a Realm object, and once I have created this object, I need to update it constantly using time intervals. Once I get the newly created object _id, I use it to update this current object instantly. The error I am getting is: 'Exception in HostFunction: Accessing object of type Post which has been invalidated or deleted
and when I log the newly created _id from the react native app and compare it to the one in MongoDB they are different:

```html
// this is the object creation function
const created_post = handleAddPost();

  watchId.current = Geolocation.watchPosition(
    async position => {
      realm.write(() => {
        let updated_post = realm.create(
          'Post',
          {
            _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(created_post._id),
            body: 'My trip',
            coords: [
              ...created_post?.coords,
              {
                lat: position.coords.latitude.toString(),
                long: position.coords.longitude.toString(),
              },
            ],
          },
          'modified',
        );
      });
```

Also, sometimes I get an error that I think is related to the above issue. When I create a new object from the React Native app, it is saved successfully in the MongoDB database. But when I make some manual changes from MongoDB, I get this error: {'category': 'realm::sync::ClientError', 'code': 112, 'is fatal': True, 'message': 'Bad changeset (DOWNLOAD): Failed to apply received changeset: Update: No such object: Post in class 'ObjectId{6460f24bd60bc9ad4c93d080}' (instruction table: Post, version: 165, last_integrated_remote_version: 268, origin_file_ident: 10, timestamp: 264004727013)'}.